# Speed up postgis query in django

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, postgis

I have a postgis query that is taking on average 550 ms.

Here is what the query looks like:

```
pnt = fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (lat, lng))
Location.objects.filter(geometry__distance_lte=(pnt, D(mi=2)))
```

Is there anyway to speed this up? Would this be something I could cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can speed it up! Use [dwithin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin) instead of distance, so that the query can use a spatial index.

```
Location.objects.filter(geometry__dwithin=(pnt, D(mi=2)))
```

The database column needs to have a [spatial index](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes) in order to take advantage of this.